# How to branch multiple paths in Airflow DAG using branch operator?

Tags: python, airflow

This is what I want, but I don't know how to achieve this in airflow, as both of the tasks are being executed.

[image]

To summarize:

- T1 executes
- T2 executes
- Based on the output of T2 I want to *either* go `option_1 -> complete` or `option_2 -> Do_x, Do_y -> complete`

How should I structure this? I have this as my current code:

```py
(t1 >> t2 >> option_1 >> complete)
(t1 >> t2 >> option_2 >> do_x >> do_y >> complete)
```

t2 in this case is a branch operator.

I've also tried the syntax for `... [option_1, option_2] ...`  but I need a completely separate path to execute, not just a single task to be switched.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dependencies you have in your code are correct for branching. Make sure `BranchPythonOperator` returns the `task_id` of the task at the start of the branch based on whatever logic you need.  More info on the `BranchPythonOperator` [here](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/apache-airflow/modules/branchpythonoperator).  One last important note is related to the "complete" task.  Since branches converge on the "complete" task, make sure the `trigger_rule` is set to "none_failed" (you can also use the `TriggerRule` class constant as well) so the task doesn't get skipped.

Quick code test for your reference:

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

from datetime import datetime


DEFAULT_ARGS = dict(
    start_date=datetime(2021, 5, 5),
    owner="airflow",
    retries=0,
)

DAG_ARGS = dict(
    dag_id="multi_branch",
    schedule_interval=None,
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    catchup=False,
)


def random_branch():
    from random import randint

    return "option_1" if randint(1, 2) == 1 else "option_2"


with DAG(**DAG_ARGS) as dag:
    t1 = DummyOperator(task_id="t1")

    t2 = BranchPythonOperator(task_id="t2", python_callable=random_branch)

    option_1 = DummyOperator(task_id="option_1")

    option_2 = DummyOperator(task_id="option_2")

    do_x = DummyOperator(task_id="do_x")

    do_y = DummyOperator(task_id="do_y")

    complete = DummyOperator(task_id="complete", trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED)

    t1 >> t2 >> option_1 >> complete
    t1 >> t2 >> option_2 >> do_x >> do_y >> complete
```

[image: DAG with BranchPythonOperator]

Comment: Thats a nice example! thank you! I would like to ask you something though, when I apply this, in the tree view I see two times the same operator, the complete operator. Is this normal?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, that is expected. The Tree View displays a full branch from root to leaf. In the above example the "complete" task is the leaf node (end node) in the path that has "t2", "option_2", "do_x", and "do_y" as well as the path which contains "t2" and "option_1".  You will see the "complete" task twice because it's two distinct paths.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized it a moment later :)